# Wordpress wp_get_recent_posts always order by title

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the defaults of the "wp_get_recent_posts" Function to get and order by title name.

I know how to do it with

```
$args=array('orderby'=> "title",'order'=> "ASC");
$recent_posts = $this->wp_get_recent_posts($args);
```

My question is how can i add these $args to the function wp_get_recent_posts from child-theme functions.php file with a hook/filter without editing other files.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I meant to wp_get_recent_posts http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts set Defaults to order by title. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of doing this. There is no no filters supplied for `wp_get_recent_posts`. Check the source code [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2991)

Answer (score 0):

Use function [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
      'numberposts' => 10,
      'orderby' => 'post_title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
?>
```

Comment: My question was How could i set that wp_get_recent_posts / getRecentPosts would always have these args as defaults ('orderby' => 'post_title',      'order' => 'ASC') from a the functions.php file in a chils theme.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct way to set a new "default" for the function.

The only feasable way I see is to write your own wrapper-function:

```
function wp_get_recent_posts_title( $args = array(), $output = ARRAY_A ) {
    $defaults = array( 'orderby' => 'title' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    return wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output );
}
```

You call this function just like the original, it will forward all parameters, with the exception that 'orderby' will be 'title' when it is not set explicitly.

Of course this will only work where you call it, it will not change any other calls to the original function.